# match only string that starts with colon (:)

Tags: regex, powershell

I just started learning regex and I need some help with this newbie issue. I'd like to get the string or line that starts with a colon (:).

Here's the example of string below.

```
$string = "
# :test
# :testonly
:test
:testonly
"
```

I'd like to get the line ":test" using regex. I tried the pattern below but it doesn't work. I'm getting a False result

```
$string -match '^\:test(?!\S)'
```

If I use

```
'\:test(?!\S)'
```

The result is True but I'm getting this

```
"# :test"
```

instead of

```
":test"
```

I hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `^\:test(?!\S)` pattern is looking good, you have 2 easy options, one is to split your string into an array of strings, this can be done with `-split`, then use this pattern with `-match` to filter those matching strings:

```
$string -split '\r?\n' -match '^:test(?!\S)'
```

The other easy option is to enable your regex for multi-line matching of `^` and `$`, this can be done by using the `(?m)` flag:

```
if($string -match '(?m)^:test(?!\S)') {
    $Matches[0]
}
```

As aside, escaping of `:` with `\` is unneeded.